# Generating function for the number of surjections

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, hypergeometric-function

Let $S_k^n$ be the number of possible surjections from a set of $k$ elements to a set of $n$ elements. We have
$$\begin{align}
&S_0^0 = 1,\qquad\forall k>0: S_k^0 = 0,\\
&S_n^n = n!,\qquad\forall k<n: S_k^n = 0,\\
&\forall k>n>0: S_k^n = n(S_{k-1}^n + S_{k-1}^{n-1}).
\end{align}$$
The last relation can be seen as follows: let $\phi:\underline{k}\to\underline{n}$ be a surjection. Consider the subset $\underline{k-1}\subset\underline{k}$ consisting of the first $k-1$ elements $\{1,2,\ldots,k-1\}$. Then either the restriction of $\phi$ to $\underline{k-1}$ is a surjection, and $\phi(k)$ is any element of $\underline{n}$, or the restriction misses exactly one element among the $n$ elements of $\underline{n}$, and $k$ is mapped to this missed element. Representing the first terms in a grid, we have
$$\begin{array}{c|cccccc}
n\backslash k & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\
\hline
0 & 1 & \color{lightgray}{0} & \color{lightgray}{0} & \color{lightgray}{0} & \color{lightgray}{0} & \color{lightgray}{0} & \color{lightgray}{0} \\
1 & \color{lightgray}{0} & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
2 & \color{lightgray}{0} & \color{lightgray}{0} & 2 & 6 & 14 & 30 & 62\\
3 & \color{lightgray}{0} & \color{lightgray}{0} & \color{lightgray}{0} & 6 & 36 & 150 & 540\\
4 & \color{lightgray}{0} & \color{lightgray}{0} & \color{lightgray}{0} & \color{lightgray}{0} & 24 & 240 & 1560
\end{array}$$
If we extend $S_k^n$ to $n,k<0$ by setting it to zero everywhere, then the last relation is satisfied everywhere except at the point $(k,n) = (0,0)$.

I am interested in the generating function of these numbers, that is
$$S(x,y) = \sum_{k,n\in\mathbb{Z}} S_k^nx^ky^n.$$
Using the relation above, we obtain
$$\begin{align}
S(x,y) = & 1 + \sum_{k,n\in\mathbb{Z}}n(S_{k-1}^n + S_{k-1}^{n-1})x^ky^n\\
= & 1 + xy\left(S(x,y) + (1+y)\frac{\partial S}{\partial y}(x,y)\right).
\end{align}$$
Moreover, we have the boundary conditions $S(x,0) = 1 = S(0,y)$. According to [WolphramAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281-x*y%29*S%28x%2Cy%29+%3D+1+%2B+x*y*%281%2By%29*dS%2Fdy), this is solved by
$$S(x,y) = c(x)\left(\frac{y}{(y+1)^{x+1}}\right)^{\frac{1}{x}} + (y+1)^{-\frac{x+1}{x}}{}_2F_1\left(-\frac{1}{x},-\frac{1}{x};\frac{x-1}{x};-y\right).$$
(This was edited after an error in the original question was found by @MickA)

Now, just by looking at the equation we know that this function will automatically satisfy the required boundary conditions. How can we fix the function $c(x)$? I am a bit at loss (also because I'm not familiar with hypergeometric functions at all). Also, is it possible derive a closed expression for $S_k^n$ from the resulting solution?

***Remark:*** I already know of the formula obtained by inclusion-exclusion principle:
$$S_k^n = \sum_{i = 0}^n(-1)^i\binom{n}{i}(n-i)^k$$
for $0\le n\le k$. I am curious to see if this alternative method works, if it gives exactly the same answer, and if it contains any additional information in general.

Comment: On how you arrive at your PDE, I expand from the previous line as follows. $\sum_{k,n\in\mathbb{Z}}nS_{k-1}^nx^ky^n = xy(\partial{S}/\partial{y})$ which seems to agreee with you. But $$\sum_{k,n\in\mathbb{Z}}nS_{k-1}^{n-1}x^ky^n = \sum_{k,n\in\mathbb{Z}}(n-1)S_{k-1}^{n-1}x^ky^n + \sum_{k,n\in\mathbb{Z}}S_{k-1}^{n-1}x^ky^n = xy^2(\partial{S}/\partial{y}) + xyS(x,y)$$

So I get PDE: $$(1-xy)S(x,y) = 1 + xy(1+y)\frac{\partial S}{\partial y}(x,y)$$

Of course, it's possible I made a mistake. :-)

Comment: @MickA You're right, thank you. I will edit my question.

Answer (score 0):

The number of surjections from (n) to (k) is the number of  ways to divide (n) elements into (k) non-empty subsets
(given by the Stirling number of the second kind, $\genfrac{\{}{\}}{0pt}{}{n}{k}$) times the number of ways to arrange the $k$ sets to match them to the function values ($k!$). So you want $k! \genfrac{\{}{\}}{0pt}{}{n}{k}$. No simple formulas, sorry. But there are several formulas relating them, and generating functions.